# перегрузка оператора сложения в сложном случае шаблонных классов

Tags: c++, gcc, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть набор шаблонных классов, наследуемых от одного базового класса:

```
template<typename Traits>
class Base{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  virtual ~Base(){}

  virtual scalar_t apply(const scalar_t&) const=0;
};

template<typename Traits>
class Pover_of_Number:
public Base<Traits>{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  Pover_of_Number(const scalar_t& power):
  power(power){}

  scalar_t apply(const scalar_t& value) const override{
    return pow(value,power);
  }
private:
  scalar_t power;
};

template<typename Traits>
class Mult_by_Number:
public Base<Traits>{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  Mult_by_Number(const scalar_t& num):
  num(num){}

  scalar_t apply(const scalar_t& value) const override{
    return num*value;
  }
private:
  scalar_t num;
};

template<typename Traits>
class SumOperator:
public Base<Traits>{
  typedef Base<Traits> BT;
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  SumOperator(const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op1,
              const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op2):
  op1{op1}, op2{op2}{}

  scalar_t apply(const scalar_t& value) const override{
    return op1->apply(value)+op2->apply(value);
  }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<BT> op1;
  std::shared_ptr<BT> op2;
};
```

Следующий код для конкретного набора свойств работает без проблем:

```
class TraitsExample{
public:
  typedef double scalar_t;
};

int main(){
  typedef typename TraitsExample::scalar_t scalar_t;

  auto op1=std::make_shared<Pover_of_Number<TraitsExample>>(2.);
  auto op2=std::make_shared<Mult_by_Number<TraitsExample>>(10.);

  auto sumop=std::make_shared<SumOperator<TraitsExample>>(op1,op2);

  scalar_t value=2.;
  std::cout<<sumop->apply(value)<<std::endl;
}
```

Имея такой набор классов мне необходимо перегрузить оператор `+`. К примеру:

```
template<typename Traits>
std::shared_ptr<SumOperator<Traits>> operator+(
  const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op1,
  const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op2){
  return std::make_shared<SumOperator<Traits>>(op1,op2);
}
```

Однако при компиляции такого кода возникает проблема с автоматическим распознаванием шаблонов и возникает ошибка `template argument deduction/substitution failed`.

Может кто-нибудь предложить код, позволяющий правильно осуществить перегрузку оператора сложения в данном случае?

PS: для удобства вы можете найти [код по ссылке](http://cpp.sh/8bnsl)

Comment: На мой взгляд это и есть минимальный пример. Есть три наследника класса, использующие паттерн TypeTraits. Необходимо из этих трех классов перегрузить оператор сложения 3=1+2. Сложность заключается именно в присутствии всех этих компонентов вместе, поэтому упрощение просто уберет эту проблему как таковую.

Comment: Эээ, вы хотите оператор сложения для (умных) _указателей_?

Comment: А что в этом неправильного? Я могу произвольным образом перегружать любые операторы. Я же не пытаюсь _сложить_ эти указатели, я явным образом задаю тип, возвращаемый перегруженным оператором - новый указатель на известный объект, который _знает_ что именно нужно сделать при вызове функции-члена.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, Ваш код (точнее проблемную его часть) можно упростить до следующего:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
struct B {};

template <class T>
struct D : B<T> {};

template <class T>
void operator+ (const std::shared_ptr<B<T>>&, const std::shared_ptr<B<T>>&) {}

int main()
{ 
    std::shared_ptr<D<int>> sd(new D<int>);
    std::shared_ptr<B<int>> sb = sd;
    
    sd + sb;
}
```

В таком варианте он [не компилируется](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PWsSHsMT2rA655Xy). Причина в том, что типы аргументов в шаблонных функциях не допускают неявного преобразования. Т.е. нельзя например вместо `std::shared_ptr<B<T>>` использовать `std::shared_ptr<D<T>>`, т.к. они не связаны отношением "базовый - производный", а всего лишь имеют соответствующие преобразующие конструкторы.

Если первый аргумент исправить на `const std::shared_ptr<D<T>>&`, то код [уже соберется](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ggeJyTqmaHPk9kJO).

Или можно сделать оператор нешаблонным:

```
//template <class T>
void operator+ (const std::shared_ptr<B<int>>&, const std::shared_ptr<B<int>>&) {}
```

в таком случае компиляция тоже будет [успешной](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VEcBIVgs5gB6rkmK).

Какое из этих решений подойдет Вам лучше - решайте сами:

1. Сделать наследование между реальными типами аргументов.
2. Поправить сигнатуру на более частный случай.
3. Сделать функцию нешаблонной.